# Kindly help me debug this python program, with list iteration error

Tags: python, debugging, runtime-error

**Question :**

- To find the percentage of 2 sentences matching.
- If 100%, Print "Exact Match!"
- Ignore the difference of 1 character between any 2 words being checked. (1 character error margin)

**Program :**

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

 def difWord(s1, s2):

        m = len(s1)
        n = len(s2)

        if abs(m - n) > 1:
            return false

        count = 0
        correct = 0

        i = 0
        j = 0
        while i < m and j < n:

            if s1[i] != s2[j]:
                count+=1

        if count==1:
            return true




    def seqMatch(a,b):

        rat = SequenceMatcher(None,a,b).ratio()

        if rat==1 :
            print("Exact Match!")
        else :
            print(rat*100)



        splitted1 = a.split()
        splitted2 = b.split()

        c=0
        for x,y in splitted1.iteritems(),splitted2.iteritems() :

            if difWord(x,y) :
                c+=1;

        per = (count*100)/4
        print(per)



    if __name__ == "__main__":

        a = "He is a boy"
        b = "She is a girl"
        c = "He is a boy"

        seqMatch(a,b)
```

**Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\eidmash\Documents\Demo-Project\Day0.py", line 59, in <module>
    seqMatch(a,c)

  File "C:\Users\eidmash\Documents\Demo-Project\Day0.py", line 43, in seqMatch
    for x,y in splitted1.iteritems(),splitted2.iteritems() :
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: -> Has been Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your traceback, the error is in the line:

```
    for x,y in splitted1.iteritems(),splitted2.iteritems():
```

The method [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) returns a list, thus it isn't a dictionary that would provide the [`iteritems`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) function.  However you can just iterate through the two list at a time with the help of the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function.  Modify that line to:

```
    for x, y in zip(splitted1, splitted2):
```

Otherwise, without the use of that `zip` function to bundle the items of the two lists together, Python will interpret that as iterating through the two items which happen to be the two lists, yielding them for use in the for loop (actually will cause an error if the lists themselves don't have exactly two items as they will be unpacked into `x` and `y`), which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

try

`for x,y in zip(splitted1,splitted2)`

Comment: I did. Thank you!